# Method error - missing return statement in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to finish a linked list activity but I'm having an error message saying "missing return statement" right after the very last curly brace of this code. What's wrong with this?

```
public boolean insertNode(DataElement insertItem)
{
    LinkedListNode current;
    LinkedListNode trailCurrent;
    LinkedListNode newNode;

    boolean found;

    newNode = new LinkedListNode();
    newNode.info = insertItem.getCopy();

    newNode.link = null;

    if(first == null)
    {
        first = newNode;
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        trailCurrent = first;
        current = first;
        found = false;

        while(current !=null && !found)
            if(current.info.compareTo(insertItem) >= 0)
                found = true;
            else
            {
                trailCurrent = current;
                current = current.link;
            }
        if(current == first)
        {
            newNode.link = first;
            first = newNode;
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            trailCurrent.link = newNode;
            newNode.link = current;
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `public boolean insertNode` says you should return a boolean, if you dont want to return anything change to `public void insertNode`. If you want to return if the node addition was successful, return true after inserting the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean insertNode
```

returns a boolean. If you want to do something in a function without returning anything, just replace

```
public void insertNode
```

Return value is SUPER important in all programming languages. Get used to always put the correct return value of a function (If you precised it on the function's prototype).

In your case, you should return the only boolean variable you're using
`return found;`

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean insertNode
```

Three parts in that declaration:

`public` -- Tells about the accessibility of this method. Public means that any class can access it.

`boolean` -- The method should return a boolean value to the caller. You can use `void` if you dont want to return anything.

`insertNode` -- name of the method.

So a method is constructed in the following way:

`Accesscontrol returnType methodName`

Can have following values:

```
AccessControl: private, public, protected
returnType: int, boolean, String, void, List etc etc -- Limited just by imagination. 
methodName - should be meaningful verb.
```

So when you ask your method to return a boolean, you call it the following way:

```
boolean insertSuccessful = insertNode(dataElement);
```

now insertSuccessful will contain a true or false value, depending if the insert was successful.

If your method was void, it would return nothing and the caller wouldn't expect a value to be returned and hence no insertSuccessful variable.

Answer (score -1):

//by using void return type

public static void diff(int x, int y) {

//calculate difference

```
      int z = x - y;
```

//print the difference here instead of the main() method

```
     System.out.println(z);
```

}

Comment: The solution is that the return type of the method should be 'void', which was already stated in another answer. Please only post another answer if the given answers are missing an essential part of the solution.